# Are DAG files needed for non-mining nodes

Tags: go-ethereum, mining

DAG files are needed for Ethereum proof-of-work system: https://github.com/ethereum/wiki/wiki/Ethash-DAG

However are these files necessary for non-mining clients e.g. geth full nodes that do not mine?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

the DAG is needed for the mining (POW).

> when you start up your node from scratch, mining will only start once
> the DAG is built for the current epoch.

from the [DOC](https://github.com/ethereum/wiki/wiki/Mining#ethash-dag) :

> **Automatic DAG generation is turned on and off** when mining is
> controlled from the console. It is also turned on by default if geth
> is launched with the --mine option. Note that clients share a DAG
> resource, so if you are running multiple instances of any client, make
> sure automatic dag generation is switched on in at most one client.
>
> To generate the DAG for an arbitrary epoch:
>
> geth makedag   For instance geth makedag
> 360000 ~/.ethash. Note that ethash uses ~/.ethash (Mac/Linux) or
> ~/AppData/Ethash (Windows) for the DAG so that it can shared between
> clients.

epoche = 30000 blocks, a 125-hour window.

so DAG is not necessary for nodes that didn't mine

Comment: Automatic DAG generation is turned off for the mining node, does it have a bad impact ?